# Set state to initial state after clicking the submit button

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm fetching data from back-end and displaying it on reactjs front-end. I have a form where we enter the some string in the input then it displays the output. I have to refresh the page everytime to display new data. I am looking to set my state to null after we enter the submit button. The problem here is I already have one event handler assigned to the submit button. How can I set my state to null after clicking submit button and display my output at the same time.

```js
const [myData, setMyData] = useState(null);
const [endP, setEndP] = useState(null);

const inputHandler = (event) => {
  setMyData(event.target.value);
};

const buttonHandler = (event) => {
  event.preventDefault();
  setEndP(`http://localhost:1000/userData?Q=${myData}`);
};

<form onSubmit={buttonHandler}>
  <input type="text" onChange={inputHandler} />
  <button type="submit">Get It</button>
</form>;
```

Comment: did you try `const inputHandler = (event) => {
  myData = event.target.value;
  setMyData({ myData });
};`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can Perform that by making the input field in your form a *Controlled INPUT* by providing a `value` attribute and `onChange` handler. with that the initialState `myData` can't be null, If you set It initialy to null your input field will be blocked and you can't modify it value. Learn more here [Controlled Input](https://reactjs.org/docs/forms.html#controlled-input-null-value)

```
const FormComponent = (props) => {
    const [myData, setMyData] = useState("");
    const [endP, setEndP] = useState(null);

    const inputHandler = (event) => {
        setMyData(event.target.value);
    };

    const buttonHandler = (event) => {
        event.preventDefault();
        setEndP(`http://localhost:1000/userData?Q=${myData}`);
        setMyData('')
    };

    return (
        <form onSubmit={buttonHandler}>
            <input value={myData} type="text" onChange={inputHandler} />
            <button type="submit">Get It</button>
        </form>
    )
    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I probably think that you need to cancel out event.preventDefault()
So your page will get refreshed automatically as your button type is submit and the state will again be changed to null

Comment: The page will also get refreshed in this way automatically

Comment: I cant fetch data after cancelling event.preventDefault()